# Glowing lines via nodes

Tags: materials

How do I add glowing lines on a cube or anything that have vertices on Blender 2.8? I'm a beginner so I thought adding material should work. There is another thread where it explains that but I cannot make only the vertices glow. Also it would be great if I could make the lines a bit thicker. I'm trying to make a on/off button which has glowing lines around.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pointiness from the Input Geometry Node
But as you can see here from these wire-frames the geometry plays a big part.

[image: wire frames of different density Cubes]

Using a Mix Shader with a BSDF Shader and an Emission Shader and controlling the effect with a Color Ramp
[image: glowing edges from pointiness]

Of course, you could remove all the extra geometry that does not affect the effect.

Answer (score 1):

For better/other results then pointiness node you can do it with bevel node minus normals setup:

[image]

Material Setup:
[image]

Compositor Setup:
[image]